# how to plot line from x-axis and y-axis for a specific point

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If I have this matrix which represents X-axis:

```
Data1=[1
1;
2;
3;
3;
6;
9;
14;
15;
16;
28;
31;
97;
152;
226]
```

and I have this equation to get the represented values of each element in Y=axis:

```
for i=1:numel(Data1)
     p1(i)=(i - 0.3 )/( numel(Data1) + 0.4)     
 end
```

So, X-axis is Data1, and Y-axis is p1.
My question is: how can I plot a line for a specific point on Y-axis (e.x at p1=0.62) and from X-axis, which both of the lines will cross each other.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**`interp1`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to find the according x-value for your given y-value.

```
Data1 = [1;1;2;3;3;6;9;14;15;16;28;31;97;152;226]
for i=1:numel(Data1)
    p1(i)=(i - 0.3 )/( numel(Data1) + 0.4);     
end

plot(Data1,p1); hold on

%// given y-value
pY = 0.62;

%// determine according x-value
pX = interp1(p1,Data1,pY);

%// plot 
plot( [pX,pX], [0,pY],'k-','LineWidth',3); hold on
plot( [0,pX], [pY,pY],'k-','LineWidth',3);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @thewaywewalk, Can I plot these lines in Weibull plot equation wblplot(Data1)

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi of course! just use `hold on` if you want to use multiple plot commands

Comment: Can you please substitute plot(Data1,p1) with wblplot(Data1) and see the result. It is not as we want!

Comment: well what do you want then?

Comment: I want to usw Weibull equation which is wblplot(Data1)  , then I want to plot the lines at 0.62, can you please explain how to modify your code to do it? So sorry for bothering you but I ma not professional in Matlab

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi The Weibull Probaballity plot just uses `Data1` which is 1D-Data. Your given `p1 = 0.62` is an y-value. What line do you want exactly in your weibull plot? A vertical line which intersects with the straight line at 0.62? please be clear what you want, I don't want to guess everything...

Comment: Using p1 and Data1 plot, is similar to wblplot(Data1) plot. p1 is showing the way of calculating Y-axis in wblplot(Data1). Now, I want to plot lines for X-axis and Y-axis when the value of Y-axis is 0.62 by using wblplot(Data1). I hope it is clear sir.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it by looking at the element in `p1` that is closest to the value of interest. That is, subtract that value from `p1` and find the smallest element. To account for both positive and negative values, I square the difference vector and then take the square root to get only positive values. Otherwise the `min` function will look for the negative value farthest from 0.

Note that this method finds the point closest to your actual curve and as such is less precise than using interpolation. To see how to do it with `interp1` have a look at @thewaywewalk's answer.

The code is commented so easy to follow:

```
Value = .62

%// Find index in p1 closest to the value of interest.
Diff = sqrt((p1-Value).^2);

[~,b] = (min(Diff));

%// Plot the curve
plot(Data1,p1)

%// Adjust axis limits
axis([0 max(Data1(:)) 0 max(p1(:))])

%// Add lines
hLine1 = line([0 Data1(b)],[Value Value],'LineWidth',3,'Color','k');
hLine2 = line([Data1(b) Data1(b)],[0 Value],'LineWidth',3,'Color','k');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Note that it does not use interpolation to find exact value on the curve. See @thewaywewalk's answer for that.

Comment: SOrry, if I use wblplot(Data1), would it be possible to plot these lines?

Comment: Absolutely the principle is the same

Comment: I did wblplot(Data1) then hold on then plot( [pX,pX], [0,pY],'k-','LineWidth',3); hold on; plot( [0,pX], [pY,pY],'k-','LineWidth',3); but the results is not right. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
hold on;

plot(Data1, p1, 'b-'); 

p1Val = 0.62;
idx = find(p1 == p1Val, 1);
plot([0, Data1(idx)], repmat(p1Val, 1, 2), 'k-', 'LineWidth', 2); % Horizontal line
plot(repmat(Data1(idx), 1, 2), [0, p1Val], 'k-', 'LineWidth', 2); % Vertical line
```

Comment: This won't work as `p1 == p1Val` will return an array of just zeros.

Comment: Thanks Sir, Can I plot these lines in Weibull plot equation wblplot(Data1)